# Stack Overflow "Newest" answer order?

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

Some info may be outdated when you see a Stack Overflow question from years ago. So sometimes you may be better off checking the newest answers first for a question. You can order the answers for a question on Stack Overflow by Active, Oldest, or Votes, but there is no "newest" option.

Comment: **active** is what's most recently updated so even an old answer may have up to date information in it.

Comment: At first I thought: click "Oldest" and scroll to last one. But honestly, why do we have "Oldest" instead of "Newest"? That doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be a less awkward way to do this, but it’s still somewhat possible. Simply search for [inquestion:########](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Inquestion%3A927358) with the id of the question in Stack Overflow’s search and sort by newest.

Answer (score 3):

We already have this in a way; the Active option will show questions at the top that have the newest activity, which includes newest answers.

However, I'm not sure why you would want to see the *questions* page sorted by newest *answer*... an answer without the context of a question is pretty useless.